# how to bind these valuesin a gridview( which has 3 values as one row)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview whose values are binded in

Day      period1  period2  period3

Monday    maths    nill     english

### in this format

i have binded in a gridview that shows three records as

Day      period1  period2  period3

Monday    maths    nill     english

Monday    maths    nill     english

Monday    maths    nill     english

---

but how to bind these values in a gridview since monday will have 3 records / values..

how to bind the periodwise subjects and timings inside gridview. how to get these records binded oly once in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need to do:

- A pivot operation in the database to get it in the format you need.
- Code to take the three values and convert them to columns (you can programmably create a DataTable object to store the data, then loop through the records and create your flattened UI).

HTH.